# 16.04 LTS server, how to install CUPS without ImageMagick

Tags: 16.04, server, printing, imagemagick

My apologies if this has already been answered, I did quite a bit of searching with no luck.
Ubuntu Server 16.04, I had to compile/install ImageMagick from source, because the ImageMagick package from the Ubuntu repository was throwing memory allocation errors when attempting to manipulate image files using the "convert" and "mogrify" commands.
The compiled/installed ImageMagick version 7.0.8 resolved the problem with processing image files, but removing the stock ImageMagick packages also removed CUPS and it's dependencies.
I need CUPS back, I have to be able to print, but I also need a working version of ImageMagick to process files received via HylaFax.  How can I re-install CUPS without it reloading the broken ImageMagick packages and clobbering my working installation of ImageMagick?  My apt skills are apparently insufficient for this task.